# Paypal IPN 500 HTTP response Code

Tags: paypal

I am getting a 500 error in the HTTP response code for my paypal IPN. It usually fails up to about 9 times and then will go through. What could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you receive any response from PayPal? If yes, you can check the received params to know more about the issue.  Otherwise, something's wrong with your PayPal acc

Comment: This has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with your PayPal account. HTTP 500 is the response code PayPal gets from your server when PayPal attempts to send the IPN data to it. Check your PHP/Apache error log to find out why it's failing (ideally, tail the error log while it attempts to (resend) data to it.)

Comment: I called my hosting provider because I have the same intermittent error. They told me that it is caused by how my application is configured (web.config, etc) and they give me a website from Microsoft that have documentation about how to configure for optimal performance but didn't gave me a direct response of how to solve this. The link is https://msdn.microsoft.com/library under Development Tools and Languages. Now I have to do a research to see if I can find the answer to that. If I solve this, I will post the answer here.